# Java Swing is not Thread-Safe; does that mean no two person can modify its specific feature e.g. JcomboBox at the same time

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcombobox

Hi I am relatively new to Java Swing. I am working on an application which uses Swing related Classes and methods like JComponent, JPanel, JComboBOx.

I read documents saying Swing is not thread safe. Does that mean like if I have a JComboBox in a Graphical User Interface (with/without editable option), no two person can modify the Box at the same time (or cannot access it).

Struggling to understand this concept.

Comment: Not thread safe means no one is responsible if something breaks while you manipulating swing components outside swing thread.

If you have multiple threads that can modificate swing components - you should use SwingUtilities.invokeLater.

Comment: if question about reading data from component in multiple threads - it's not a problem. you can get not a consistent data, nothing more. in case of reading - one solution is to use atomic containers and update them from eventLisntener from your component

Answer (score 2):

What it means is that once a Swing component is showing on the screen, any modifications must be done on the Swing GUI thread.

See SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable), SwingWorker, and javax.swing.Timer

Comment: so GUI construction(before setVisible) can be done outside EDT?

Comment: @hunter It can be. Before a component is visible, the EDT is unaware and uninterested in it. But some prefer to do this also in the EDT